# Finding combinations of combinations that are distinct

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Let's say we have a list with a length of l=8:

```
[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
```

I am trying to calculate the number of all possible combinations of n by m, in this example n=2 and m=3, so that one possible combination would be:

```
[[a,b,c],
 [d,e,f]]
```

and another would be:

```
[[g,h,c],
 [d,e,f]]
```

or

```
[[a,b,f],
 [d,e,c]]
```

The order does not matter at any level. However, elements must not repeat, meaning the following list would be incorrect, and should not be counted:

```
[[a,b,c],
 [e,f,c]]
```

And

```
[[a,b,c],
 [e,f,c]]
and
[[e,f,c],
 [a,b,c]]
```

would be the same thing, and should be counted once. Similarly,

```
[[a,b,c],
 [e,f,c]]
and
[[a,b,c],
 [c,f,e]]
```

is the same thing, and should be counted once.

So a complete set of solutions for

```
[a,b,c,d]
```

where n=2 and m=2, would be:

```
[[a,b],
 [c,d]]

[[a,c],
 [b,d]]

[[a,d],
 [b,c]]
```

I have (manually) computed some values:

| l (number of elements) | n (rows) | m (columns) | size |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 15 |
| 6 | 2 | 2 | 45 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 10 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose $mn$ of the $l$ numbers and arrange them in a line in one of $(nm)!$ ways.  Put the first $m$ numbers in the first row, the next $m$ numbers in the second row, and so on.  Since the order of the elements in a row doesn't matter, we must divide by $(m!)^n$.  Also, the order of the rows themselves doesn't matter, we must divide by $n!$.  In short $$\binom{l}{nm}\frac{(nm)!}{(m!)^nn!}$$

Comment: Thank you! However, this would produce the same solution if the choice was from 4 or 5 numbers, as in the example in the table. In other words, it assumes that l=mn, but it might be that l>mn.

Comment: @JoosepL Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough.  I'll revise.